# What in the world is going on? / What's going on in the world?

Tags: questions

> **What in the world is going on?**
>
> **What is going on in the world?**

It seems I'm surprised and don't understand why is used the first version, not the second one? Could you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[what/who/how/where/etc] in the world" is a phrase of its own, with a distinct meaning:

> From the [Merriam-Webster entry for *world*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world): "Among innumerable possibilities : EVER —used as an intensive"

Note, this usage relies on the "question word" (who/what/etc) being included as part of the phrase. When your second example breaks it up and separates "what" from "in the world":

> What is going on in the world?

... then this meaning is lost, and "in the world" simply becomes a participial phrase, added to "What is going on."

Comment: Another idiom with the same meaning is _what on Earth?_

Answer (score 2):

Because idioms are idioms, and (even more than other elements of language) are often not rule-governed or logical.

In particular, idioms tend to be more or less fixed. Some elements of them may be changed, but not others.

So, for example, the idiom *what in the world* can be extended to *why in the world*, and *who in the world*, and even to *where in the world* (though that is often literal), but not to other question words such as *when* or *which*.

But reordering it to move *in the world* out of the idiom loses the idiomatic meaning completely, and leaves only its literal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *What in the world is going on?*, you are asking what is going on in the context. When you say *What is going on in the world* you are literally asking what's happening in the world.

*What in the world is going on?* is an expression, people do not mean in literally.